# HTML img srcset not behaving as intended?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, srcset

I am trying to load responsive images and things seem to be working in the latest version of firefox. However, my images are not loading as intended in Safari and Chrome.

```html
<img 
  src="/images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_1000.jpg" 
  srcset="/images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_400.jpg 400w, 
          /images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_600.jpg 600w, 
          /images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_800.jpg 800w, 
          /images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_1000.jpg 1000w"
  alt="Blank" 
/>
```

The goal is to have each of these images load on their respective screen. `02_exterior_400.jpg` should load on screens less than 400px. `02_exterior_600.jpg` loads on screens less than 600px, etc. Each of these images should be taking up 100vw.

On Chrome (see below) my page is at 386px but it's loading the 800px image and I want it to load the 400px:

[image: Improperly loading images]

Same issue on Safari. What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit: Chrome/Safari seem to be doubling my screen width when deciding which image to load. For example: if my screen is at 350px the browser is interpreting it at as 700px and then loading `02_exterior_800.jpg`.

Any help appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the "sizes" attribute. Also, put the regular "src" attribute *after* the "srcset" attribute. This is used as a fallback if the first srcset is either not supported, or the images are not found.

```
<img srcset="/images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_400.jpg 400w,
             /images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_600.jpg 600w,
             /images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_800.jpg 800w,
             /images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_1000.jpg 1000w"
     sizes="(max-width: 400px) 400px,
            (max-width: 600px) 600px,
            (max-width: 800px) 800px,
            1000px"
     src="/images/pages/arrivals/02_exterior_1000.jpg" alt="A Sense of Arrival">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Didn't seem to work unfortunately. From my understanding `sizes` is an optional attribute that when left blank is implicitly considered `100vw` by browsers.

Comment: sizes defines a set of media conditions (e.g. screen widths) and indicates what image size would be best to choose, when certain media conditions are true...Without the sizes attribute the browser doesn't know which image to display: [mozilla responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)